# How can I group a list of objects by two attributes in one iteration?

Tags: java

I'm trying to group a large list of objects by two of their attributes. To demonstrate what I mean, consider the following example.

```
public class Foo {

    private String attributeA;
    private String attributeB;
    private String anotherAttribute;
}
```

I want to group a large list of `Foo` objects by the attributes `attributeA` and `attributeB`. Currently I do the following.

```
List<Foo> foos = getFoos();
Map<Set<String>, List<String>> groupedFoos = Sets.newHashMap();
Set<String> fooGroup;
for(Foo foo : foos) {
    fooGroup = Sets.newHashMap(foo.getAttributeA(), foo.getAttributeB());

    if (!groupedFoos.containsKey(fooGroup)) {
        groupedFoos.put(fooGroup, Lists.newArrayList(foo));
    } else {
        groupedFoos.get(fooGroup).add(foo);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same result without using a `Map` like `Map<Set<String>, List<String>>`? It is important to do this in one iteration. The values of the attributes `attributeA` and `attributeB` can be swapped. So using `Pair` as the key of the `Map` is also not an option.

Comment: If you can override `Foo.hashCode` why not implement it hashing a sorted combination of both attributes and use that as the map's key? Or just use `Sets.newHashMap()` as you are but sorting tthe attributes beforehand.

Comment: I also cannot override hash code, modifying the entities is not possible in this case. As I don't have access to them.

Comment: @maraca I don't want to sort, I just want to group by two parameters.

Comment: Then maybe implement your own key class or hash them off and use the hash as the key. Sorting would be a way to satisfy the `a` and `b` values are interchangeable requirement.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this use case would be for using lambdas? I think Java 8's Collectors might [help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) you.

Comment: The easy solution is to use a Map and concatenation of the attributes as key using a delimiter that is guaranteed to never appear in any of the attributes used for the key.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of `Map` as key, you can always write your own `Key` in a way that will compare both attributes (regardless of their order).

```
public class Key {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Key foo = (Key) o;

        if (a.equals(foo.a) || a.equals(foo.b)) {
            return true;
        }

        return b.equals(foo.b) || b.equals(foo.a);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = a.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + b.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a key method to your class.

```
public class Foo {

    private String attributeA;
    private String attributeB;
    private String anotherAttribute;

    public final String getKey() {
      return this.attributeA + "$" + this.attributeB; //use $ or any other delimiter as suggested in the comment
    }
}
```

Then if you can use Java8, use `Collectors.groupingBy()` method like below

```
 final Map<String, List<Foo>> result = getFoos().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo:getKey));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned in my question: the values of the attributes can be swapped.

Comment: you need a delimiter, e.g. (12, 3) and (1, 23) gives the same key othewise. @Javiator then order them first.